# Can someone explain why this code keeps looping?

Tags: java

i'm still quite new to java, can someone explain when i enter a value that meets the requirements (1-10) that the code keeps looping back to the initial for loop? How can i amend the code to fix the problem and allow to function properly?

```
public void rateEpisode(Scanner sc, String seriesName, int searchEpisodeNumber, ArrayList<TVSeries> tvSeries) {
    for(int i = 0; i<tvSeries.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j< tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().size(); j++){
            if((seriesName.equals(tvSeries.get(i).getTitle())) &&
                    (searchEpisodeNumber == tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).getEpisodeNumber())){
                System.out.println("Please enter your rating(1-10) of " + tvSeries.get(i).getTitle() + ", Episode " + tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).getEpisodeNumber() + ". " 
                    + tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).getEpisodeName() + " : ");
                boolean validInput = false;
                int userEpRating = -1;
                do{
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    validInput = false;
                    if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                        userEpRating=sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();
                        if(userEpRating < 11 && userEpRating > 0){
                            validInput = true;
                        } else{
                            System.out.println("Please enter a rating between 1 and 10: ");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }
                }while(!validInput);
                tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).setUserEpReview(userEpRating);
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Sorry not clear.  You have three loops here: two for loops that are well bounded, and an inner do/while.  Can you clarify the behavior you're observing?

Comment: for for if while...

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).setUserEpReview(userEpRating);
```

to here:

```
if(userEpRating < 11 && userEpRating > 0){
    validInput = true;
    tvSeries.get(i).getListOfEpisodes().get(j).setUserEpReview(userEpRating);
    return;
}
    ...
```

and add `return` after it.

 When you call `return` in a method that returns nothing (`void`) then the method exists immediately.

Comment: @ImmortalDB what happens when you run it?
try to check if the program ever gets to that if

Comment: It gets to the if statement where valid input becomes true, but then it just starts the first for loop over again.

Comment: thanks for the help, i got it working, i took out the two for loop and added the i and j variables to the parameter of the method and messed around with how i was calling the method.

Comment: @ImmortalDB so my answer helped you? I'm confused... if it did, you might consider accepting it

Comment: It didn't help per say but you took the time to answer and i appreciate it

Comment: @ImmortalDB no problem at all